Problem in login with firebase and admin sdk
We use the firebase athentification to login and check the session of user. But we d'ont know why, the serveur make a 500 code error.
In the web, we have this:
POST https://www.falc-on.fr/login?_data=routes%2Flogin 500 (Internal Server Error) 
But on the serveur we have this on the getUserSession:
Here is the log :
chunk-42MHJKLU.js:13 getApps lenght 0
chunk-42MHJKLU.js:13 firebaseConfig-service initialized
chunk-42MHJKLU.js:13 getApps lenght 1
chunk-42MHJKLU.js:13 PRODUCTION MODE
root-F6643RGT.js:1 (NAVBAR.TSX) isAuthenticated in navbar false

root-F6643RGT.js:1 (NAVBAR.TSX) isAuthenticated in navbar false
login-XUOTFOW4.js:1 (LOGIN.TSX) LOADER DATA  false
login-XUOTFOW4.js:1 (LOGIN.TSX) RENDER FUNCTION 
chunk-RPSJ7XPS.js:17 
        
        
       POST https://www.falc-on.fr/login?_data=routes%2Flogin 500 (Internal Server Error)
ce @ chunk-RPSJ7XPS.js:17
await in ce (async)
Ge @ chunk-RPSJ7XPS.js:23

This error came from after authentication in a function named createUserSession:

export async function createUserSession(idToken, redirectTo){
  if (!idToken || typeof idToken !== 'string') {
    return json(
      {
        errorCode: 'session/invalid',
        errorMessage: 'Invalid session',
      },
      { status: 422 },
    );
  }
  
  console.log("IDTOKEN: ",idToken);
  console.log("ADMINGAUTH: ",adminAuth);
  console.log("VERIFY ID TOKEN: ",await adminAuth.verifyIdToken(idToken));
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;

  return adminAuth.verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then(decodedToken => {
      console.log("session tokenGOT !!!");
      adminAuth.createSessionCookie(decodedToken, {expiresIn});
      return getSession()
        .then(session => {
          console.log("session:", session);
          session.set("userId", decodedToken.uid);

          if (redirectTo) {
            console.log("if success");
            return commitSession(session)
              .then(cookie => redirect(redirectTo, {
                headers: {
                  "Set-Cookie": cookie
                },
              }));
          } else {
            console.log("else success");
            return commitSession(session)
              .then(cookie => json(
                { status: "success" },
                {
                  headers: {
                    'Set-Cookie': cookie,
                  },
                  status: 201,
                }
              ));
          }
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error in session creation:", error);
      return json(
        {
          errorCode: 'session/create',
          errorMessage: 'Could not create session: ' + error + " // ID Token: " + idToken,
        },
        { status: 500 }
      );
    });
}

And on the vercel Logs nothing is coming on this line :
 console.log("VERIFY ID TOKEN: ",await adminAuth.verifyIdToken(idToken));

And this is the error of the vercel console that shows up:
   at FirebaseTokenVerifier.mapJwtErrorToAuthError (/var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-verifier.js:266:20)
   at /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-verifier.js:246:24
   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
 errorInfo: {
   code: 'auth/argument-error',
   message: 'Firebase ID token has invalid signature. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.'
 },
 codePrefix: 'auth'
}

I correctly initialized the admin sdk in my project :
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount2 = JSON.parse(process.env.ADMIN_SERVICE_ACCOUNT.toString());
Object.values(serviceAccount2).forEach(value => {
  if (value === undefined) {
    console.error("One or more Firebase configuration values are undefined.");
  }
});
console.log("Firebase Admin Initialized; Apps Length:", admin.apps.length);
let authInit;
try{  
  if (!admin.apps.length) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      process.env['FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST'] =  '127.0.0.1:9099';
      console.log("FIREBASE AUTH EMULATOR HOST:", process.env['FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST']);
      process.env['FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1:8085';
      console.log("FIRESTORE EMULATOR HOST:", process.env['FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST']);
      process.env['FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1:9199';
      console.log("FIREBASE STORAGE EMULATOR HOST:", process.env['FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST']);
      authInit = admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount2),
      });
   }
   else{
    authInit = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount2)
    });
    console.log("PRODUCTION MODE ADMIN INITIALIZED");
   }
  }
  console.log("Firebase Admin Initialized; Apps Length:", admin.apps.length);
}
catch(e){
  console.log("Firebase Admin Error:", e);
}

export const auth = admin.auth(authInit);

I just want to point out that i did not touched the domain verification with the admin sdk account on Google admin workplace, and my domain name is registered in the auth verified domains.
If anyone has an idea for a solution, thanks in advance.
I was expecting a login or the creation of a cookie. I works on local btw with the emulators
